# Dart / Flutter - abstract class not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a generic dropdown widget with the current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class FormDropdownProtocol {
  String get title;
}

class FormDropdown<FormDropdownProtocol> extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormDropdown({this.value, this.items, this.onChanged});

  final FormDropdownProtocol value;
  final List<FormDropdownProtocol> items;
  final ValueChanged<FormDropdownProtocol> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<FormDropdownProtocol>(
      value: value,
      items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<FormDropdownProtocol>>(
          (FormDropdownProtocol value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<FormDropdownProtocol>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value.title),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error when trying to use the title:

> Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
>    - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named > 'title'.
>              child: Text(value.title)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know why but declaring the class like this `class FormDropdown<T extends FormDropdownProtocol>` and then using T across the class fixes everything. If anyone know why and cares to explain, I'd love to hear about it. Otherwise, I'll answer my own question in a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```dart
> class FormDropdown<FormDropdownProtocol> extends StatelessWidget {
> ```

This defines a generic class (`FormDropdown`) with a type parameter named `FormDropdownProtocol`.  That type parameter could be named anything; it might be clearer to understand what's going on if it were:

```dart
class FormDropdown<T> extends StatelessWidget {
```

Dart generics aren't like C++ templates where the class is instantiated with the formal type information before everything is resolved.  With Dart, everything is resolved before the generic is instantiated with a type.

In the case of `class FormDropdown<T>`, nothing is known about `T`.  No constraints are given, so it can only be deduced to be an `Object`.  And indeed, `Object` has no `title` member.

If you instead do `class FormDropdown<T extends FormDropdownProtocol>`, then `T` is now constrained to be `FormDropdownProtocol`, which does have a `title` member.